# ZF2: configuring new abstract factories

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2.2.0, a bunch of [new abstract factories have been added](http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-2-0-stable-released.html). I want to configure a database logger, but I am not sure how to do this. The link gives the following example of configuring a stream logger:

```
'log' => array(
    'Application\Log' => array(
        'writers' => array(
            array(
                'name'     => 'stream',
                'priority' => 1000,
                'options'  => array(
                    'stream' => 'data/logs/app.log',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I have tried to copy the configuration into `config/global.php`, and I also attempted to nest it under the `service_manager` key. It says that I should be able to fetch the logger directly from the service manager, but I get an error saying that it could not create an instance of `Application\Log`. Did I misunderstand something here? Where should the configuration be added?

Also, in my concrete example, I want to use a database writer. How is this configured in a similar style to the above (i.e. with arrays)? When looking at the `Zend\Writer\Db` [constructor](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Db.php#L73-L75), it requires an adapter instance to be passed. I am not sure how to do that without making a factory, because my database adapter is using an abstract factory itself; `Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory`. That seems to require me to access the service manager within the configuration file to fetch the database adapter, in order to inject it into the db writer. I am not sure if that is even possible.

I can make a custom factory just fine, but I like the idea of these consistent abstract factories; I am just confused as to how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need to enable the abstract factory that creates the logger, e.g. with the following config

```
// ... snip ...
'service_manager' => array(                                                 
    'abstract_factories' => array(                                          
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',                            
    ),                                                                      
)
// ... snip ...
```